# Publishing and Subscribing Vectors

Tags: ros, c++, add-message-files, array, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

How can I receive a vector (with unknown length and contains three floats) over Publisher and Subscriber in C++?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215072/publishing-and-subscribing-vectors/) by [hsoltani](https://answers.ros.org/users/15361/hsoltani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2015-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you want a dynamic array of geometry_msgs/Vector3 by defining your own message type ?

Like this:

Vector3Array.msg:

```
geometry_msgs/Vector3[] data
```

---

Question in Comment:

PubSub Tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

To Create your own message, follow this:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsoltani](https://answers.ros.org/users/15361/hsoltani/) on 2015-08-02**:
That's right. I guess I should use std_msgs/Float32MultiArray type. Can you give some tips? How can I write publisher and subscriber or create my own message?

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-08-02**:
see my edited answer ;-)

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-08-03**:
Is anything unclear yet? (Just ask because you edited your question with no change...)